# Replacing Text in database based on key values in another in R

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to normalize a DB in R.  The DB contains a table with Authors with their respective primary keys (see table A).
[image]

Table A
I need to replace the names of the Authors in a second table (see Table B) with their correspondent primary key (id_library).

Table B
[image]

I have tried merge but I guess, my knowledge of R is still too archaic

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind `dplyr`, I'd do it like this:

```
library(dplyr)
B %>% 
  rename(Authors = id_authors) %>%
  left_join(A, by = "Authors") %>%
  select(-Authors)
```